# How can I disable an SDL Tridion UI extension in the ribbon based on a user group in SDL Tridion 2011?

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions

I was able to hide my extension by accessing the current user's group membership with the following code in the `command.js`:

```js
MyUIExtensions.MyAlternatePublish.prototype.isAvailable = 
  function MyAlternatePublish$isAvailable(selection) {

var showOption = false;
var groupsWithAccess = ["Publisher"];  // Specify all access groups here

var groups = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User.Data.GroupMemberships;

if(groups["@title"] == undefined)  // 1 group membership
{
    if(groups.Group["@title"] == groupsWithAccess[0])
        showOption = true;
}
else
{
    // many group memberships
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var userIsInGroup = groups[i]["@title"];
        length = groupsWithAccess.length;
        while(length--) {
           if (userIsInGroup.indexOf(groupsWithAccess[length])!=-1) {
               showOption = true;
               return showOption;
           }
        }
    }
}

return showOption;
};
```

I am trying to do something similar for the button that appears in the ribbon, and I read that you cannot hide them from the ribbon, and can only disable them. When I attempt to access the user's group membership via `Tridion.UI.UserSettings` in the `IsEnabled` method, the console says that this value is not defined.

Does anyone have any suggestion for either hiding/disabling a custom UI extension?

Comment: Exactly which property is it complaining about?

Answer (score 5):

The `IsEnabled` method is there to enable the button, the `IsAvailable` for actually hiding/showing it.

Robert Curlette wrote a nice article about this, see http://www.curlette.com/?p=1117

You can load the details of the current user via:

```js
var user = $models.getItem(Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings()["User"]["@ID"]);
```

But then you will have to ensure the user object is fully loaded, which is not something you can do in an `isEnabled` or `isAvailable` method (since you cannot delegate this method to wait for the loading of the User object). However you can access the group membership data directly from the JSON object too:

```js
var membershipIds = "";
var array = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings()["User"]["Data"]["GroupMemberships"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    membershipIds += array[i]["@href"] + ",";
}
```

Which will give you comma separated String with all TCM URIs of the groups that the current User belongs to.

Comment: The boolean parameter to getJsonUserSettings is for synchronous loading. He's already passing in true (=sync), so the settings should be loaded correctly. I'm not sure why it isn't working for him.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was using Robert Curlette's approach, though the null check on GroupMemberships was ultimately what was breaking for me. getJsonUserSettings returns "undefined" if a user only has one membership, and an array if multiple memberships. Luckily my case is either admins (no membership) or people with 2 or more, so I was able to loop through the array. Thanks again!

Comment: @kir the undefined means you got an object returned (it is not the same as null indeed), which will be the group info that the user is member of. Assign it to a variable and you will be able to see what it is. Indeed it is a bit tricky to work out when it is a single object or an array of objects, my code is expecting multiple groups, so I fell for the same problem again.